# Can the iPhone simiulator detect swipe gestures?

Tags: iphone, iphone-sdk-3.0, uigesturerecognizer

I have a question with UISwipeGestureRecognizer class

Can the iPhone simiulator detect the UISwipeGestureRecognizer?

Kindly let me know your answers

Comment: The original title wasn't very descriptive. It's important to have a complete, self-contained title for the main page, as only the title is listed. It's also important for search engines, as the title is often given extra weight when indexing pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/Xcode/Conceptual/iphone_development/125-Using_iOS_Simulator/ios_simulator_application.html%23//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007959-CH9-SW3), yes.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it can recognize all gestures but multitouch ones (you have only one mouse cursor, right?).

An exception is the pinch gesture, if you press the ALT key and move your mouse you will see two dots, that's for pinch gestures.